# android how to put sub-menu within submenu

Tags: android, submenu

I want to add a submenu to an existing submenu with this xml:

```
<item android:id="@+id/chooseCountry" android:title="Choose Country">
    <menu>
        <item android:id="@+id/india" android:title="India" >
            <menu>
                <item android:id="@+id/blor" android:title="Bangalore" />
                <item android:id="@+id/delhi" android:title="Delhi" />
                <item android:id="@+id/hyd" android:title="Hyderabad" />
            </menu>
        </item>
        <item android:id="@+id/pak" android:title="Pakistan" />
        <item android:id="@+id/africa" android:title="South Africa" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

I am getting but this exception:

```
08-15 12:57:50.942: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(312): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempt to add a sub-menu to a sub-menu.
```

I do not understand what I am doing wrong - can anybody give me some advice?

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be natively supported from Android API level 15.  On earlier versions, a workaround is to redirect menu calls.  Using your xml example, change it so that the sub-sub-menu is a regular **hidden** menu item, and add a redirect place holder item instead:

```
<item android:id="@+id/india" android:title="India" android:visible="false">
    <menu>
        <item android:id="@+id/blor" android:title="Bangalore" />
        <item android:id="@+id/delhi" android:title="Delhi" />
        <item android:id="@+id/hyd" android:title="Hyderabad" />
    </menu>
</item>


<item android:id="@+id/chooseCountry" android:title="Choose Country">
<menu>
    <item android:id="@+id/india_redirect" android:title="India" />
    <item android:id="@+id/pak" android:title="Pakistan" />
    <item android:id="@+id/africa" android:title="South Africa" />
</menu>
```

Hang on to the inflated `Menu mOptionsMenu` created in `onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu )` and open the sub-menu from your redirect like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected( int id, MenuItem item) 
{
    switch ( item.getItemId() ) 
    {
      case R.id.india_redirect:
        mSomeView.post( new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                mOptionsMenu.performIdentifierAction( R.id.india, 0 );                  
            }
        } );

        return true;
    }

    return super.onMenuItemSelected( id, item );
}
```

Note the call to `performIdentifierAction` is posted from a `View` to the UI message queue.  On old versions of Android it can be called immediately, but on newer versions it needs to be a separate message to work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, apparently this is not supported. You'll have to redesign your menu.

Comment: but how? Plz give me any idea.

Comment: Morne's solution above is just working fine I suggest you give it a try. I'm using minSdkVersion 5 and solution worked.